# Dynamics AX Synchronization Errors

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue when synchronizing my Dynamics AX 2012 data dictionary with the SQL Server.

It is giving errors on a variety of tables/views, complaining of no valid runable code.  The problem is, I've deleted all the offending objects from the AOS.  I also checked the SQL Server, and they are not present on there either.

Not really sure to turn next.  How do you fix an item that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try have a look at this. It's about sync errors on deleted items:
http://www.agermark.com/2013/11/odd-synchronization-issues-in-ax-2012.html

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

See [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Deleting the extra records from the SQLSyncInfo table corrected my problem.